# Como solucionar? ¡Acceso prohibido!, Error 403, quiero abrir mi proyecto pero me suelta este error

Tags: xampp

¡Acceso prohibido!, Error 403.

Quiero abrir mi proyecto en xammp pero no logro entrar porque siempre me salta ese error.
resulta que solucione el error de phpmyadmin pero no de mis otros proyectos.
¡Acceso prohibido!
Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al directorio solicitado. No existe un documento índice, o el directorio está protegido contra lectura.

Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.

```
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
```

Comment: Supongo que es un proyecto que funcionaba en otro lado y XAMPP funciona bien verdad?? Que te dice la consola??